# How to nest dynamic queries in zend framework?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I want to design a filtration system for my website.
I have items with following details:

```
 id     category     price
 1        2           11
 2        1           10
 3        1           23
 4        3           27
 5        3           36
 6        2           42
```

I want to write a query something like this using zend classes

```
`SELECT * FROM item WHERE category IN (1,2) AND (price BETWEEN 10 AND 20 OR price BETWEEN 41 AND 50)`
```

The whole price bracket has to be generated through code something like

```
`$select->from('item');
$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
$where->in('category', array(1,2));
$where->and->nest;
foreach($input as $in) {
    $where->between('price', $min, $max)->or;
}
$where->unnest;
$select->where($where);`
```

Now this code generates the following query which is wrong

```
`SELECT * FROM item WHERE category IN (1,2) AND () AND price BETWEEN IN 10 AND 20 OR price BETWEEN 41 AND 50`
```

Now Please help me to generate a query as the former using zend framework classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nest functions returns a new PredicateSet that will be nested. that is why its not working for you, so if u change it to this. it should work

```
$select = $sql->select('item');
$where = new Where();
$where->in('category', array(1,2));
$nest = $where->and->nest();
foreach($input as $in) {
    $nest->between('price', $min, $max)->or;
}
$select->where($where);
```